# Can someone please look at my queue?

Tags: c, function, queue

I am using Dev C++. The program crashes as soon as I enter a name into the queue and press enter

```
void queue (Client c[])
{
    int choice,tail=0,max=20,front=0,ch,w;
    char queue [20];

    do {
        printf ("Do You Want To (1)Enter Clients To A Queue or (2)Remove Clients From A Queue?");
        scanf ("%d",&choice);
    }while (choice<1 || choice>2);

    if (choice==1)
    {
        if (tail==max-1)
        {
            printf("Queue is full!");
            return;
        }

        tail++;
        printf("Enter Client Name:");
        scanf (" %[^\n]",queue[tail]);            
        if (front==-1)
            front++;
    }
    else if (choice==2)
    {
        if (front==-1)
        {
            printf("Queue is empty!");
            return;
        }
        printf("Enter Client Name To Remove:");
        scanf (" %[^\n]",queue[front]);
        if (front==tail)
            front=tail=-1;
        else
            front++;
    }

    do {
        printf ("Do You Want To (1)Queue More Clients or (2)Continue?");
        scanf ("%d",&ch);
    }while (ch<1 || ch>2);

    if (ch==1)
    {
        void queue (Client []);
        queue (c);
    } 
    else if (ch==2)
    {
        do{
            printf ("Do You Want To Go Back To (1)The Main Menu Or (2)Exit?");
            scanf ("%d",&w);
        }while (w<1 || w>2);

        if (w==1)
        {
            void main_menu (Client[]);
            main_menu (c);   
        }
        else if (w==2)
        {
            void end (Client []);
            end (c);
        }
    }                 
}
```

Comment: Turn on your warnings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a multidimensional character array to hold the name. What you are trying to do is that accepting the name in single character. How it can be?

Just change the Code :

```
char queue [20];
```

to the :

```
char queue [20][20];
```

Comment: also, for a queue of 20 elements, you can use only 0-19 indexes. queue[20] doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep. Exactly. But i am just suggesting him to use two-dimensional character array so that he can use in that queue application. Now the size is depends on programmers that how many record he/she wants.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something is wrong here:

```
printf("Enter Client Name:");
scanf (" %[^\n]",queue[tail]);
```

you are trying to enter a name (which is an array of char) to an element of queue (which is a char). Maybe you should change it to :

```
printf("Enter Client Name:");
scanf (" %[^\n]",queue);
```

Your code has room for improvement. Some important things to test:

1. Use a different name for your queue variable (distinguish it from your queue method).
2. Your queue variable should be declared globally not in the function.
3. Youe queue variable should be like this: char* queueVariable[20]; it should be an array of names (which itself is an array of chars).
4. The queue bound controller variables should be declared globally too.